# Сделать универсальное регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно сделать регулярное выражение, которое будет удалять предыдущий символ перед текстом `<backspace>`. Казалось бы, это реализуется очень просто:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @".<backspace>", "");
```

Но тут есть подводные камни. Если, например, в тексте идет 2 `<backspace>` подряд, тогда конструкция рушится. Можно, конечно, сделать такое решение:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @".<backspace>|..<backspace><backspace>", "");
```

но это бред, ведь может быть и 10 `<backspace>` подряд и надо будет удалить 10 предыдущих символов. Как сделать универсальным это регулярное выражение?

---

Может быть такая строка:

```
string str = "это буу<backspace>дка<backspace><backspace>ет тек<backspace>стовыыф<backspace><backspace>й ткаукц<backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace>екст";
```

В итоге должны получить:

```
"это будет тестовый текст"
```

Comment: `str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?(bs)(?!))((?<bs><backspace>)|(?<-bs>.(?<!<backspace>)))+?", string.Empty, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, одной изящной регуляркой это не сделать.

Я придумал следующее:

```
Match m;
do
{
    m = Regex.Match(str, ".<backspace>");
    str = str.Remove(m.Index, m.Length);
} while (m.Success);
```

В цикле находим и удаляем по одному вхождению паттерна. Конечно, этот способ не блещет производительностью.

Comment: Сам так же в итоге сделал. Способ костыльный какой-то конечно)

Comment: RegexOptions.Compiled?

Comment: Не проще ли в таком случае искать не регуляркой, а подстрокой?

Comment: @PashaPash, зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy затем что это , возможно, будет работать чуть быстрее при вызове в цикле много раз

Comment: @PashaPash, зато память может течь...

Answer (score 9):

В .NET можно решить эту проблему регулярным выражением с проверкой состояния стека захватывающих групп:

```
^(?:<backspace>)+|(?:(?<t>(?<!<backspace).)|(?<-t><backspace>))+(?(t)(?!))(?:<backspace>)*
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%3cbackspace%3e%29%2b%7c%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3ct%3e%28%3f%3c!%3cbackspace%29.%29%7c%28%3f%3c-t%3e%3cbackspace%3e%29%29%2b%28%3f%28t%29%28%3f!%29%29%28%3f%3a%3cbackspace%3e%29*&i=%d1%8d%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%d1%82%3cbackspace%3e%d0%be%0d%0a%3cbackspace%3e%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be+%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%83%3cbackspace%3e%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%d0%b5%d1%82+%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%3cbackspace%3e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%8b%d1%84%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%d0%b9+%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%0d%0aab%3cbackspace%3ec%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3ed%0d%0a%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e%3cbackspace%3e&r=&o=m).

**Подробности**

- `^(?:<backspace>)+` - один и более последовательностей символов `<backspace>` в начале строки (`^`)
- `|` - или
- `(?:(?<t>(?<!<backspace).)|(?<-t><backspace>))+` - незахватывающая группа (`(?:...)`), находящая одну или более (`+` — жадный квантификатор, находит 1 и более последовательных совпадений) последовательностей `(?<t>(?<!<backspace).)` или `(?<-t><backspace>)`:

  - `(?<t>(?<!<backspace).)` - любой символ, перед которым нет подстроки `<backspace` (так как использован флаг `RegexOptions.Singleline`, точка также находит символ перевода на новую строку) (при этом каждое совпадение будет добавлено в стек группы `t`)
  - `(?<-t><backspace>)` - одна и более последовательностей символов `<backspace>` (при этом каждый раз при найденном совпадении из стека группы `t` будет удаляться последнее значение)
- `(?(t)(?!))` - условная конструкция: если стек группы `t` не пуст, совпадение считается неверным, и запускается поиск с возвратом (backtracking), иначе возвращается совпадение (такое, где количество значений, найденных `(?<t>.)` равно количеству значений, найденных `(?<-t><backspace>)`)
- `(?:<backspace>)*` - ноль и более последовательностей символов `<backspace>`

Можно объявить это выражение в коде следующим образом:

```
public static class Rx
{
    public static readonly Regex backspaceRx = new Regex(
        @"^(?:<backspace>)+          # 1+ <backspace> в начале
           |                         # или
           (?:
             (?<t>(?<!<backspace).)  # Любой символ, перед которым нет <backspace 
             |                       # или
             (?<-t><backspace>)      # <backspace>
           )+                        # 1 или более раз
           (?(t)(?!))                # проверка стека группы t
           (?:<backspace>)*          # 0+ <backspace>",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
}
```

[Тест на C#](https://ideone.com/oNCYKh):

```
var tests = new List<string> {"<backspace>это буу<backspace>дка<backspace><backspace>ет тек<backspace>стовыыф<backspace><backspace>й ткаукц<backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace>екст",
        "Это<backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace>",
        "a<backspace><backspace><backspace>b",
        "<backspace><backspace><backspace><backspace>",
        "ab<backspace>c<backspace><backspace>d" };
    foreach(var test in tests)
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", Rx.backspaceRx.Replace(test, string.Empty));
```

Вывод:

```
'это будет тестовый текст'
''
'b'
''
'd'
```

Comment: Ничего себе! А где можно об этом почитать? (Если есть хорошая книга, может быть, добавите её в [список литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105)?)

Comment: Всё, что я знаю о регулярных выражения, почерпнуто из англоязычных источников. О стеке, условных шаблонах, балансировочных группах можно почитать [здесь на русском](http://qaru.site/questions/3801/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups).

Comment: Жаль, что нету русскоязычных книг. А можно ссылку на англоязычный оригинал вопроса? Очень уж машинный перевод глаз режет. // Ага, нашёл: [What are regular expression Balancing Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799/276994). Пусть полежит здесь для будущих читателей.

Comment: Попробуйте `string str = "a<backspace><backspace><backspace>b";` в качестве входных данных. Или `string str = "ab<backspace>c<backspace><backspace>d";`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: http://ideone.com/DfMHKb. Нужно отсеять ненужные совпадения, уточнив `.` с помощью предварительного блока просмотра назад и удалить непарные `<backspace>`.

Comment: `string str = "<backspacex<backspace>>";`

Comment: @PetSerAl: А это уже не понятно, входит ли в условие. Если так, то уже и `a<bX<backspace>ackspace>`. Думаю, это не будет валидным текстом в грамматике вопроса.

Comment: Вообще-то, можно обойтись только регулярным выражением. Надо отловить все `<backspace>` после проверки стека. Да, вряд ли это валидно.

Comment: Ничего себе, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew И всё-таки для ввода `ab<backspace>c<backspace><backspace>d` ваш код возвращает `ad`, вместо `d`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Если есть ещё примеры, давайте. А решение я обновил.